# How does split method work when using a non-whitespace character in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I do not understand how the `split()` method from String class works when using `regex` (a non-whitespace character). I have found some partial anwsers on the internet but i still don't understand. Here is my code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String myX = "x xx ";
        String[] x = myX.split("\\S");

        for (String s : x){
            System.out.print("\"" + s + "\", ");
        }
        System.out.println(x.length);
    }
}
```

My logic is as follows:

Is the first `'x'` a non-whitespace? Yes, so in the array we should have `""`
Is the `' '` non-whitespace? No, so in the array we should have `" "`
Is the second `'x'` a non-whitespace? Yes, so in the array we should have `""`
Is the third `'x'` a non-whitespace? Yes, so in the array we should have `""`
Is the last `' '` non-whitespace? No, so in the array we should have `" "`

In my opinion the array should look like this: `["", " ", "", "", " "]`

Why the array looks like `["", " ", "", " "]` and has the length 4 in stead of 5? In the middle are located 2x, not only one as in the array appears.

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't the resulting elements simply `0x1 x2x3 `? Why would `xx` result in *two* empty strings?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Mixing the matches into the array: `[ "", "x", " ", "x", "", "x", " " ]` I.e, `" xx "` has a space to the left, an empty string inbetween the `x`s and a space to the right. In your logic you say it'll produce two consecutive empty strings, but wherefrom would the second one come?

Comment: There are 3 non-whitespace characters in that string; the most parts it can be split into is 4. But the fact it's whitespace or non-whitespace is irrelevant - try swapping the `x` and `_` around, and use `"\\s"` as your delimiter - you'll see exactly the same pattern in the output.

Comment: @AlexM. Note that this has little (or nothing) to do with either regex or whitespace. You get the same result if you split by a literal `x`.

Comment: @Biffen Yes, you are right. Nicolas Filotto's answer helped me understand to way this method works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question that you should rather ask yourself is what do we have between 2 consecutive separators?

1. When it finds the first `x`, the extracted value is `""` because the previous separator is virtually the beginning of the `String`
2. When it finds the second `x`, the extracted value is `" "` because the previous separator was the first `x` and `" "` is what we have in between
3. When it finds the third `x`, the extracted value is `""` because the previous separator was also the previous character so there is nothing to extract
4. When it finds the end of the `String`, the extracted value is `" "` because the previous separator was the third `x` and we have a space in between.

So the result is indeed `"", " ", "", " "`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a visual way of explaining how the `split()` method applies the delimiter:

```
^x xx $
[    ""    |   " "   |    ""    |   " "   ]
^  nothing ^  space  ^ nothing  ^  space  ^
start    1st x      2nd x      3rd x      end of string
```

This results in the array output you observed:

```
["", " ", "", " "]
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, A bit late, but wanted to put it.

What your logic tells is something like this

> Go through each character if it is a non-whitespace character make it blank otherwise put the same character.

```
    String myX = "x xx ";
    String[] x = new String[myX.length()];
    char[] charArray = myX.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        char c = charArray[i];
        x[i] = !Character.isWhitespace(c) ? "" : String.valueOf(c);
    }
    for (String s : x){
        System.out.print("\"" + s + "\", ");
    }
    System.out.print(x.length); // prints "", " ", "", "", " ", 5
```

**Your given code will work like below**

1. The first non-whitespace character is first `x` it will give
   everything left to it:- `""`
2. The second non-whitespace character is second `x` it will give
   everything between first and second x:- `" "`
3. The third non-whitespace character is third `x` it will give
   everything between second and third x:- `""`
4. There is no non-whitespace characters so it gives everything right
   to third `x` as last element.

So the result is `["", " ", "", " "]`.